# Optimizing yuv420p to rgb565 conversion with Tegra?

Tags: android, android-ndk, tegra

When my android application native code runs on NEON processor I'm taking advantage of the fast NEON assembler instructions to convert yuv420p to rgrb565.

Is there something similar for Tegra processors though?

Comment: Tegra 3 has NEON as well. Tegra 2 has nothing.

Comment: In other words, the ARM SIMD instruction set called NEON is a standard feature on most Cortex-A8 and Cortex-A9 processors. The NVidia Tegra2 does not include NEON, but the Tegra 3 does. There are no other standard instruction set extensions for ARM related to multimedia.

Comment: @BitBank If you care to put this as an answer I will be glad to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARM SIMD instruction set called NEON is a standard feature on most Cortex-A8 and Cortex-A9 processors. The NVidia Tegra2 does not include NEON, but the Tegra 3 does. There are no other standard instruction set extensions for ARM related to multimedia that matter. Marvel had a MMX variant added to their StrongARM and PXA series while Intel owned them, but they are no longer relevant.